# Find all Rows that Child table contains all Ids in given parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following SQL tables:

```
create table User (
  UserId int not null primary key clustered (Id)
)

create table dbo.UserRole (
  UserId int not null, 
  RoleId int not null,
    primary key clustered (UserId, RoleId)
)
```

Given a parameter RolesIds I need to get Users that have UserRoles for all those RolesIds.

If the parameter RolesIds has no values then no User is returned.

How can create such query?

Comment: What have you tried, why didn't it work? Sample data and expected results?

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```sql
select UserId, count(*) cnt 
from Userrole 
where RoleId in RolesIds 
group by UserId 
having cnt = Number_of_RolesIds
```

for example

```sql
select UserId, count(*) cnt 
from Userrole 
where RoleId in (1,2,3) 
group by UserId 
having cnt = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the approach that I would use (I pasted the code that you can test without underlying database, not that RoleIds variable is of xml type which can be queried for the values):

```
declare @UserRole table
(
  UserId int not null, 
  RoleId int not null,
  primary key clustered (UserId, RoleId)
) 

insert into @UserRole
values (1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 1), (2, 3)

declare @RoleIds xml = N'<R><I ID="1"/><I ID="2"/><I ID="3"/></R>'

select distinct
mt.UserId
from @UserRole as mt
where not exists(select 1 from @RoleIds.nodes('/R/I') as x(items)
             where x.items.value('@ID', 'INT') not in (select ur.RoleId from @UserRole as ur where mt.UserId = ur.UserId)
             )
```